# What happens to the Universe if a quantum coin in a black box is secretly flipped for zillions times?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, quantum-computer

First, let us using an [IBM](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/) quantum processor (QP) to run the following simple quantum circuit:
[image]

The [IBM](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/circ-comp/q-gates)  $U_3 (\pi/3,0,0) $ gate transforms the initial state $q[0] = \vert0\rangle$ to a biased quantum coin: 
$\vert q\rangle = U_3\vert0\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}\vert0\rangle + \vert1\rangle\right)$. 
Every time the state $\vert q\rangle$ is measured, a binary value either $0$ or $1$ (with 75% and 25% chance respectively) is recorded. I tried it few days ago and it only took the IBM processor about 2.4 seconds to run the circuit for 4096 times, displaying a histogram with 74.927% of $0$'s and 25.073% of $1$'s, from the data stored in the classical register c5.

Now assume that the QP is locked in a sealed black box with a controlling robot, which will start to the program at any time during one hour. Then what happens to the Universe?

According to the Copenhagen Interpretation, before the box is opened, only the robot knows if and when the qubit state in the box has repeatedly collapsed $4096$ times. Because each measurement is independent, we have a direct product of $2D$-Hilbert spaces, for eaxmple:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}\vert0\rangle + \vert1\rangle\right)⊗\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}\vert0\rangle + \vert1\rangle\right)=\frac{1}{4}\{3|00\rangle +\sqrt{3}[|01\rangle + |10\rangle] + |11\rangle\} 
$$
which can be written in [decimal state notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform#Circuit_implementation)  as $\{3|0\rangle +\sqrt{3}[|1\rangle + |2\rangle] + |3\rangle\}/4$. Mathematically, we can say that, before the box is opened, the QP is in the following superposition:
$$
|Ψ_{QP}\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} α_{i} |i\rangle,   \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} |α_{i}|^2 = 1, N = 2^{4096}
$$ 
Here, $i$ is the decimal value of a possible binary sequence stored in the classical register c5, e.g, $[1100...010]_{10}$; $α_{i}= \sqrt{3}^{i_0}/N$, $i_0$ 
 is the number of $0$'s in the $i$th binary sequence. After the box is opened one hour later, the QP state collapses to one of the $N$ states, based on the record in c5.  Outside the black box, nothing else is changed in our Universe nor in our minds.

According to the Many Worlds Interpretation, there is no state collapse inside the box, but each measurement would cause the Universe to split into 4 worlds. After one hour, we would have $4096$ measurements and $4^{4096} >> 10^{2000}$ worlds. Each world is real, contains a you and a me, and has the same total energy as ours ([Frank Wilczek](http://frankwilczek.com/2013/multiverseEnergy01.pdf)), although
nobody can detect the other worlds. Based on [Lev Vaidman](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds/#3.3), 
the final **quantum state of the Universe**  in our example can be written as:
$$
|Ψ_{UNIVERSE}\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} α_{i} |Ψ_{WORLD_i}\rangle,   \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} |α_{i}|^2 = 1, N = 2^{4096}
$$ 
where $i$ and $α_{i}$ are defined as before. You don't known in which one of the $N$ worlds your are currently living before the black box is opened one hour later, when you can identify your world based on the record in c5.

Then what happens if the robot goes crazy, the biased quantum coin flips forever, and the box is never opened? 
And how about [*Occam's razor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)  (entities should not be multiplied without necessity)?

*Can someone correct me if I misunderstand the two interpretations*?

Comment: Which puzzle is your real question? It seems that you are asking a several different ones, some of which are physics questions and some of which are philosophy questions.

Comment: @Anders Sandberg: My first question is physical, but I think that questions about interpretations of quantum mechanics always involve both physics and philosophy...

Comment: If you find the many-worlds interpretation useless or even nonsensical, just feel free to ignore it altogether. Its only purpose is to provide an intuitive picture of what is going on, and this does not work for everyone (it certainly does not work for me).

Comment: @Stéphane Rollandin: Thanks. Several outstanding physicists (like Einstein) do not like wave collapse, which leads to probabilistic predictions ("God plays die") and remote correlations ("Spooky action at a distance"). MWI never thinks itself is just an intuitive picture. Therefore, its attempt to get rid of state collapse cannot be simply ignored. If it does not work for you, would you please tell me why? Is it based on physics, philosophy or something else?

Comment: MWI is only an interpretation; and the formal structure of QM is the same in all interpretations. So whatever some of its proponents may say, it is only the metaphorical/philosophical/ontological picture it provides that makes it specific. If it helps build one's intuition, fine. As for me, it does not - it does not make any sense to me, it is just as hairy to navigate than QM proper, simply replacing the question of what is a measurement with the question of what is a world or what is a split, with no gain in clarity whatsoever. To me it is essentially a poor way to save determinism.

Comment: @Stéphane Rollandin Thanks for your opinion!

Comment: When asking these sorts of questions, the tiny details matter.  What causes the robot to start the process?  I ask because the wording chosen for that tends to lend itself to one interpretation or another.  They are, of course, equivalent mathematically, but if your interpretation for how the robot works is in line with the copenhagen interpretation, is is highly unlikely that the MWI interpretation of the experiment will make sense.  If your robot is started off by the action of a pilot wave, it's probably DeBroglie that you want.

Comment: @Cort Ammon: My robot has a finger to press the "Start" key on the graphic interface of the IBM quantum processor at a randomly chosen time. Nothing else is involved. Then which interpretation is more likely?

Comment: @Xmwang672 How did you construct a randomly chosen time?  Computers are not known for their ability to do anything randomly.  Indeed, many formal ways to do something "randomly" in QM experiments lend themselves to the Copenhagen interpretation.

Comment: @Cort Ammon: It is easy done in computer. For example, the robot can start the program at any time t (in milliseconds) during next one hour by using Java like: long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis(); long t = t0 + (3600000 *Math.random()).

Comment: @Xmwang672 If you look into computing, you'll find that "random" numbers like that are best called "pseudorandom."  They are actually quite deterministic and easy to predict if you know a little state information (state information that would be known before you close the box)

Comment: @Cort Ammon: I am not sure about the effect of "pseudorandom" in my example. As far as I know, in Bell tests of entangled photons,  a quantum random number generator (RNG) is used to provide the input to rotate the directions of a pair of polarisers independently (see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0402001). We can do the same.

Comment: @Xmwang672 If you are looking to use a QRNG to start off your robot, the most interesting of all of the observations, including all 4096 measurements of the QBIT, is the observation of the quantum states which are used to generate your random number  This is interestingly similar to Schrodinger's cat, in that your entire experiment is "alive" or "dead" at any time based on something that could be similar to radioactive decay of an isotope.

Comment: @Cort Ammon: Yes, you are absolutely right. My intention is to realize the famous "Schrodinger's cat" (thought) experiment with a modern quantum processor and a robot. I have changed the alive-or-dead cat to flipping an unfair coin 4096 times, so instead of just two equally-weighted options, it has 2^4096 unequally-weighted options. I hope this change would be helpful to show the differences of the two interpretations...

Comment: @Xmwang672 are you familiar with the typical arguments made regarding Schrodinger's cat and Copenhagen/MWI/Pilot wave?  If not, I can provide them here as an answer.

Comment: @Cort Ammon There are many different arguments in the literature and online. But I would like to see your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, absolutely nothing happens to the universe: if the outcomes of the flips are recorded inside the box, and the box is isolated from the rest of the universe,  *only the part of the universal wavefunction that describes the box* is affected by what goes on in the box.  Open the box, look at the record, and proceed as usual because only one of the zillions of the possible records will be seen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, according to Copenhagen Interpretation, absolutely nothing happens to the Universe. On the other hand, I really would like to know, without state collapses in the black box, how the state of the Universe is evolving according to MWI...

Comment: In your scenario, the universe evolves in two physically and mathematically separate/independent parts, until and unless the box is opened,  BOTH in the Copenhagen and the MWI view.

Comment: But, in the MWI view, whether the black box is open or not, every measurement (as a quantum transition) in the processor leads to a world split: "according to an increasingly popular analysis of quantum mechanics known as the 'many worlds interpretation', every fundamental event that has multiple possible outcomes — whether it's a particle of light hitting Mars or a molecule in the flame bouncing off your teapot — splits the world into alternate realities". (nbcnews.com/mach/science/, Oct 22, 2019). Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.  But the world (W)  is (U +B). If U and B are isolated from each other, the evolution of (W) is just the evolution of (U) plus the evolution of (B).

Comment: When (B)'s wavefunction splits it does of course split (W):  (W) -> (U) + ((B1) + (B2)), so (W1, W2) = ((U) + (B1), (U) + (B2)).  Sorry, I'm making up my notation as I write this.  I hope it is understandable if not precise. The point is that there is no interaction between the wavefunctions (U) and (B), until their mutual isolation ends.  B can split a zillion times wiyhout affecting U, though of course it part of W and therefore affects W (but only the B part of W).

Comment: According to MWI, it is the the split of the U into zillions W, not just the split of the subsystem B, because "MWI's main conclusion is that the universe (or multiverse in this context) is composed of a quantum superposition of very many, possibly even non-denumerably infinitely[11] many, increasingly divergent, non-communicating parallel universes or quantum worlds.[2]"(see: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation: Overview of the interpretation). Each recent parallel universe contains a Milky way, a Solar system and an Earth (with a you and a me)... Am I correct?

Comment: I see why you're reading the wikipedia reference that way, but that's not actually what it means.  In fact, splitting the whole thing (W) in this case amounts to leaving the majority of W (U) unchanged and splitting a tiny part of W (B) into a zillion parts.  Not until B interacts with U does the splitting propagate out into U, which is the rest of W.

Comment: It's kind of meaningless to (mathematically) split U into zillions of identical copies, each waiting to see what happens when the box is opened.  According to MWI, *all* possible measurement outcomes are superimposed in the B wavefunction; they just aren't combined in any meaningful way with U until the box is opened.

Comment: I am afraid that you are explaining MWI with your own version. Sean Carroll says in his book (Something Deeply Hidden): " In fact, it [MWI] says that there is one wave function, and only one, for the entire Universe. Further, it states that when an event happens in our world, the other possibilities contained in the wave function do not go away. Instead, new worlds are created, in which each possibility is a reality... Don’t worry about those extra worlds, he asserts — we can’t see them...". (www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02602-8). Any event, no mater if the box is opened ...

Comment: My explanation is fully consistent with your quote from Sean Carroll.  Do you understand what I mean by the following?       "W = W1 + W2, where W1 = (U + B1) and W2 = (U +B2)"  In other words, splitting of B *does* split W, but it does not split the part of W we've set aside as U.  The U in W1 is identical to the U in W2.  I think this is at the center of your confusion.

Comment: My understanding of the split of MWI: W = W1 + W2, where W1 = (U1 + B1) and W2 = (U2 +B2). Even though U1 is almost identical to U2 at the split time, they evolve independently. A person P1 in U1 will never meet the same person P2 in U2. As [Frank Wilczek] (http://frankwilczek.com/2013/multiverseEnergy01.pdf) writes: "In this precise sense those two branches describe mutually inaccessible (decoherent) worlds, both made of the same materials, and both occupying the same space". Because P1 (P2) only can see one quantum outcome O1 (O2), there is no state collapse for MWI.

Comment: If you take the B's out of your equation, it does not change anything regarding the U's and the W's, other than that the W's don't have a B component anymore.

Comment: I'm not interested in trying futlrther to convince you of something your mind is set against.  Please seek information from a physics professor, in person, at your nearest university.  An article written for laymen is almost never a reliable source, even when written by a respected physicist, because a layman by definition does not have the knowledge needed to receive a complete explanation.